# How to sort an array by two or more criteria using MergeSort?

Tags: c#

Considering that I have an array of objects of class Example, with properties A and B:

```
    public class Example
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
        public int B { get; set; }

        public Example(int a, int b)
        {
            A = a;
            B = b;
        }
    }
```

How can I sort the array in ascending order by A and, when two or more elements are equal, sort by B between them? I'm using this example of the [MergeSort](http://csharpexamples.com/c-merge-sort-algorithm-implementation/) algorithm.

```
    public void Run()
    {
        Example[] example = new Example[5] {
            new Example(500, 25),
            new Example(100, 5),
            new Example(500, 20),
            new Example(300, 15),
            new Example(500, 35)
        };

        MergeSort(example, 0, example.Length - 1);
    }
```

Sorting method:

```
    public void MergeSort(Example[] input, int left, int right)
    {
        if (left < right)
        {
            int middle = (left + right) / 2;

            MergeSort(input, left, middle);
            MergeSort(input, middle + 1, right);

            Merge(input, left, middle, right);
        }
    }

    private void Merge(Example[] input, int left, int middle, int right)
    {
        Example[] leftArray = new Example[middle - left + 1];
        Example[] rightArray = new Example[right - middle];

        Array.Copy(input, left, leftArray, 0, middle - left + 1);
        Array.Copy(input, middle + 1, rightArray, 0, right - middle);

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (int k = left; k < right + 1; k++)
        {
            if (i == leftArray.Length)
            {
                input[k] = rightArray[j];
                j++;
            }
            else if (j == rightArray.Length)
            {
                input[k] = leftArray[i];
                i++;
            }
            else if (leftArray[i].A <= rightArray[j].A)
            {
                input[k] = leftArray[i];
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                input[k] = rightArray[j];
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if it really is a MergeSort, but it works in a similar way. The section that defines the ordering is this:

```
    else if (leftArray[i].A <= rightArray[j].A)
    {
        input[k] = leftArray[i];
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest implementing `IEquatable<Example>` within the `Example` class then you can just use Linq's Sort method.

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion! It's also a good idea! I will test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking a little more and making some attempts, I realized that the solution is very simple. For each additional criteria, just add a condition block comparing if the properties of the previous block are equal and repeat the same comparison of the previous block for the new properties. In my case, the code looks like this:

```
    else if (leftArray[i].A < rightArray[j].A)
    {
        input[k] = leftArray[i];
        i++;
    }
    else if ((leftArray[i].A == rightArray[j].A) && (leftArray[i].B <= rightArray[j].B))
    {
        input[k] = leftArray[i];
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of handling this sort of thing is the routine that compares the two objects is passed in to the sort routine.

As you already figured out, the comparison routine checks A, if A matches it checks B.  (Personally, I've gone as high as F, although I can't imagine it ever got that far in production.)